# Setting gwt cookie when redirecting to other domain

Tags: java, gwt, cookies

I have a web application developed using gwt.2.5.1, java. In my application i have a link "Volex page" which will send to the request to the other server(Volex).

supppose if i open my application with "http://localhost:8085/myApp" and can see the "vloex page", once user clicks 
on the 'Volex page' it will be redirected to 'Volex server' like below.

Window.Location("http://167.23.543.34:8087/VolexSer/volex")

The above url hits the volex server which needs some inforamtion like session id, for this i have to set the session id in the cookie like below:

```
    Date cookieDate = new Date();
    cookieDate.setDate(cookieDate.getDate() + 1);
    String baseUrl = "http://167.23.543.34:8087/VolexSer/volex";
    Integer nDomainInitialPosition = baseUrl.indexOf("/");
    Integer nDomainEndPosition = baseUrl.lastIndexOf(":");
    String baseDomain = baseUrl;

    if (nDomainInitialPosition == nDomainEndPosition) {
        nDomainEndPosition = baseUrl.indexOf("/");
    }
    baseDomain = baseUrl.substring(nDomainInitialPosition + 2, nDomainEndPosition);
    Window.alert("baseDomain: " + baseDomain);
    String eWebPageUrl = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getHref();

    if (eWebPageUrl.contains("https://")) {
        Cookies.setCookie("sessionId", LoginInfo.getSessionId(), cookieDate, baseDomain, "/", true);
    } else {
        Cookies.setCookie("sessionId", LoginInfo.getSessionId(), cookieDate, baseDomain, "/", false);
    }
```

Here opening with two domains one is "localhost" other is "167.23.543.34", If i set the cookie like above, it is not showing in the request header. Can any body tell mw what is the wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Trouble is located at domain section of cookie. Cookie for one server is not available on another for security purpose (if servers not from from one domain).  I suppose you need something like cross-domain cookie, please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) or rebuild url of the request and send required information with GET\POST directly.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, but if you see my code i am setting the cookie with  "167.23.543.34" before opening Window.Location("http://167.23.543.34:8087/VolexSer/volex"), So cookie sets in the same domain

Comment: Hello @Alexander, Please let me know if i need to provide more details.

Comment: It is not all clear for me. In your code I see that baseDomain are always reference to localhost.

Comment: May be you need to change baseDomain in cookie factory to something from eWebPageUrl?

Comment: Thanks for remind me, Please look into edited code. which is some other domain.

Comment: cross-domain cookie, please follow the link or rebuild url of the request and send required information with GET\POST directly. how to do in gwt

Comment: Show how you prepare and send request to the server.

Comment: String baseUrl = "http://167.23.543.34:8087/VolexSer/volex";
 From GWT side i just hit the server like below after setting the cookie:   com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(mfpWebPageURL, "",
       "");

Comment: Is baseUrl and url of requested server the same?

Comment: sorry@Alexender, String baseUrl = "167.23.543.34:8087/VolexSer/volex";; From GWT side i just hit the server like below after setting the cookie: com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(baseUrl , "", "");

Comment: window.open(baseUrl, "");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75357/discussion-between-alexander-fedyukov-and-m-s-naidu).